# iOS 9.3 webview request html crash

Tags: ios, iphone

iOS9.3  UIWebview load the Web page crash

```
Crashed: WebThread
0  WebCore                        0x187da43dc WebCore::RenderLayerCompositor::registerAllViewportConstrainedLayers() + 572
1  WebCore                        0x187da43d0 WebCore::RenderLayerCompositor::registerAllViewportConstrainedLayers() + 560
2  WebCore                        0x187da40a0 WebCore::RenderLayerCompositor::updateCustomLayersAfterFlush() + 28
3  WebCore                        0x188793ce8 WebCore::RenderLayerCompositor::updateScrollCoordinatedLayersAfterFlushIncludingSubframes() + 32
4  WebCore                        0x187ce16c4 WebCore::RenderLayerCompositor::flushPendingLayerChanges(bool) + 160
5  WebCore                        0x187ce1610 WebCore::FrameView::flushCompositingStateForThisFrame(WebCore::Frame*) + 172
6  WebCore                        0x187ce7154 WebCore::FrameView::flushCompositingStateIncludingSubframes() + 48
7  WebKitLegacy                   0x188c41db0 -[WebView(WebViewInternal) _flushCompositingChanges] + 36
8  WebCore                        0x188632ba4 WebCore::LayerFlushScheduler::layerFlushCallback() + 44
9  WebKitLegacy                   0x188ccaecc WebViewLayerFlushScheduler::layerFlushCallback() + 36
10 CoreFoundation                 0x183da87b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
11 CoreFoundation                 0x183da6554 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
12 CoreFoundation                 0x183cd0d30 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 416
13 WebCore                        0x187cba558 RunWebThread(void*) + 456
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183a57b28 _pthread_body + 156
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183a57a8c _pthread_body + 154
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183a55028 thread_start + 4
```

I‘m do nothing when load the Web page

Comment: Great! Did you have a **question**?

Comment: post you code please.

Comment: Replace WKWebView with UIWebView solved the problem.